# traversing arrays using for loops in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I want to compare numbers from two arrays where array1[start] compares with array2 and makes comparisons with every array2 element and then increment the array1 index once its done so. Heres what ive got so far

```
for(int i=0; i<array1.length; i++){ // move along array 1 

    if(array1[i]>array2[j]){
        //do something
        }

  for(int j =0; j<array2.length; j++){ // moves along array 2
        }
}
```

Comment: What is `j` in `if(array1[i]>array2[j])`? How should Java know which variable it represents? Remember that methods are executed from top to bottom, so there is no `j` there yet. Also explain how exactly you expect your code to work. Give us some examples of arrays and explain what results you are expecting.

Comment: ah yeah my bad. Well im guessing I need a nested for loop to traverse both arrays, but im not sure if the conditions are right. I want to count how many numbers are bigger than the current array item from the other array, and then compare the next item from the current array with the other array and so on

Comment: Is the problem solved? If your problem is solved then you should mark the answer that helped resolving the problem as **accepted**. This helps other people to find what they are looking for. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you wanted.

```
for(int i=0; i<array1.length; i++){ // move along array 1
    for(int j=0; j<array2.length; j++){ // moves along array 2
        if(array1[i]>array2[j]){
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Your placement of core logic block is in the wrong scope.